# Creating a SQL query to return values from nominally formed databases

Tags: java, mysql, sql, archetypes

I am attempting to return a report from an appointment database.  I have attached my current sql query, the difficulty I am having is that when I "join" my customer contacts table ie

```
 join contacts on (customer.entity_id = contact.contact_id and contacts.arch = 'contact.phonenumber')
    join contact_detail on (contact_detail.contact_id = contacts.contact_id and contact_detail.lookup = 'mobile')
```

I immediately lose any clients that didn't have an entry on that table and the detail table, what I would prefer to achieve is that the if the client has no contact entry it returns a null for those fields.
ie 
before I added that join it might have gone

```
Name  Time note    Mobile
DAVID 8pm haircut  0412656865
Julie 8pm style
Daniel 8pm Colour  0412533535
```

but with those lines added

```
DAVID 8pm haircut  0412656865
Daniel 8pm Colour  0412533535
```

it excludes Julie because she has no contact.phonenumber

***Thats the simple question.  I would prefer that Julie be returned with a NULL value***

This system uses a mysql database with a java archetype driven front end
hence we use a entity table, act table, participations and then some detail and lookup tables.

the actual sql query is

```
select 
p.activity_start_time
, p.activity_end_time
, p.activity_start_time AS start_time
, p.activity_end_time as end_time
, a.status
, a.description AS appointmentnote
, e.name as patientname
, e.description AS patientdescription
, customer.name as customername
, customer.description as customerdescription
, sd.name as schedule_name
, eAt.name as appointment_type
, mobile.description as Mobile
from acts a
join participations p on  
a.act_id=p.act_id and a.arch_short_name='act.customerAppointment' and 
p.act_arch_short_name='act.customerAppointment'
join entities e on p.entity_id=e.entity_id
join participations pAt on a.act_id=pAt.act_id and 
a.arch_short_name='act.customerAppointment' and 
pAt.arch_short_name='participation.appointmentType'
join entities eAt on pAt.entity_id=eAt.entity_id
left join entity_relationships er ON (er.target_id = e.entity_id
AND er.active_start_time <= date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND)
AND ((er.active_end_time >= date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND)) OR (er.active_end_time IS NULL)))
left join entities customer ON 
(customer.entity_id = er.source_id AND customer.arch_short_name = 'party.customerperson')

join contacts mobile on (mobile.party_id = customer.entity_id AND mobile.arch_short_name = 'contact.phoneNumber')
join contact_classifications mb_class on (mb_class.contact_id = mobile.contact_id AND mb_class.lookup_id = '120')

join participations schedule on 
a.act_id=schedule.act_id and schedule.arch_short_name='participation.schedule'
left join entities sd on 
(sd.entity_id = schedule.entity_id)
left outer join act_details d on 
a.act_id=d.act_id
where (p.activity_start_time<date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND)
and p.activity_end_time>date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND) or 
p.activity_start_time<date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND)
and p.activity_end_time>date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND) or 
p.activity_start_time>=date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND) and 
p.activity_end_time<=date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND)) and 
(schedule.activity_start_time<date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND) and 
schedule.activity_end_time>date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")),
 INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND) or 
schedule.activity_start_time<date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND) and 
schedule.activity_end_time>date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND) or 
schedule.activity_start_time>=date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "00:00:00" HOUR_SECOND) and 
schedule.activity_end_time<=date_add((date_format('2013-07-24',"%Y-%m-%d")), 
INTERVAL "23:59:59" HOUR_SECOND)) and 
e.arch_short_name = 'party.patientpet' and 
customer.arch_short_name = 'party.customerperson'
and sd.name like CONCAT('GROOM','%')
order by p.activity_start_time, sd.name, a.act_id
```

Comment: You want to use *outer* joins.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
join contact_detail on (contact_detail.contact_id = contacts.contact_id and (contact_detail.lookup = 'mobile' or contact_detail.lookup = null))
```

or (it can depend from MySQL syntax)

```
join contact_detail on (contact_detail.contact_id = contacts.contact_id and (contact_detail.lookup = 'mobile' or contact_detail.lookup is null))
```

Comment: Michael gave me the tip that I needed to get the query working cheers mate.
Although the final change was to add
join contact_detail on 
((contact_detail.contact_id = contacts.contact_id or contact_detail.contact_id = null) 
and (contact_detail.lookup = 'mobile' or contact_detail.lookup is null))